# Problem While Selecting from table using ST_Transform

Tags: postgresql, postgis-2.0, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-10

This following query is not returning any values

```
SELECT *
FROM leads
WHERE leads.latlong && ST_Transform( ST_MakeEnvelope(78.2137, 12.5186, 78.2460, 12.5419, 4326),3587);
```

Results like:

```
latlong | id 
---------+----
(0 rows)
```

My table contains:

```
select * from leads;
                      latlong                       | id 
----------------------------------------------------+----
 0101000020110F0000EFC9C342AD8D534044696FF085092940 |  1
 0101000020110F000003098A1F638E5340E561A1D6340F2940 |  2
 0101000020110F0000174850FC188F5340006F8104C50F2940 |  3
 0101000020110F000039B4C876BE8F5340A167B3EA73152940 |  4
 0101000020110F000039B4C876BE8F5340A167B3EA73152940 |  5
 0101000020110F000039B4C876BE8F5340A167B3EA73152940 |  6
(6 rows)
```

My table description:

```
gisdb=# \d leads
                                     Table "public.leads"
 Column  |          Type           | Collation | Nullable |              Default              
---------+-------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------
 latlong | geometry(Geometry,3857) |           |          | 
 id      | integer                 |           | not null | nextval('leads_id_seq'::regclass)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to GIS SE! Please make sure your code is formatted correctly, so it is easily readable and parsable by other users. Check the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to get accustomed with formatting posts.

Comment: Do you have a typo? You seem to convert into 3587 while your data are in 3857.

Comment: What do you mean by typo? I changed it to 3857 even though it shows the same.

Comment: Typing error. With reference geometry in epsg:3587 it can't work so anyway that was a fix that you had to make, even if it was not enough.

Comment: @MosesArulvin I am quite new to postgis, but it looks like the WHERE clause isn't really testing if your coordinates actually have a spatial relationship with your envelope (i.e. intersects/is within/etc. the envelope).  aren't you suppose to throw in a st_intersect there? This doesn't explain why the query returns 0 rows tho. i would expect all rows.

Comment: @Niels, && is testing the spatial relationships of the reference geometry and the bounding boxes of the other geometries so that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You have processed your data somehow wrong.

If you run this

```
select ST_AsEWKT(
'0101000020110F0000EFC9C342AD8D534044696FF085092940'
);
```

the result is

```
"SRID=3857;POINT(78.2137 12.5186)"
```

It seems that the points have actually their coordinates in EPSG:4326 even the SRID of the geometry and metadata in geometry_columns claim that they are in EPSG:3857.

Comment: Thank you. I am new here so what shall I do further to get bounding boxes done.

Comment: You must fix your data first. How did you create or import your data?

Comment: gisdb=# \d leads;
                                     Table "public.leads"
 Column  |          Type           | Collation | Nullable |              Default              
---------+-------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------
 latlong | geometry(Geometry,3857) |           |          | 
 id      | integer                 |           | not null | nextval('leads_id_seq'::regclass)

Comment: That is my table and Getting latitude and longitude by geocode so now I need to  query for other contacts within a 10km bounding box of the record.

Comment: Concentrate on this: You have long/lat coordinates (epsg:4326) which are defined to be in epsg:3857. That's wrong, don't do anything before it is fixed. Another story is that epsg:3857 should never be used for length or area queries. You will find old questions and answers about that if you spend a few hours by searching and reading gis.stackexchange.

Answer (score -1):

Table should be like

```
 Column  |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
---------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id      | character varying(200) |           | not null | 
 latlong | geometry(Point,3857)   |           |          |
```

While inserting record

```
INSERT INTO contacts (id,latlong) VALUES ('$cid',ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint('$longitude', '$latitude'), 3857));
```

While listing

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contacts.latlong && 
    ST_Transform(ST_MakeEnvelope(-71.0574854849222, 42.3331448597059, -71.1091842534225, 42.3587974649149, 3857), 3857);
```

Comment: [EPSG:3857](http://epsg.io/3857) is a projected coordinate system, not a "latlong" geodetic coordinate system (e.g. [EPSG:4326](http://epsg.io/4326)) that the question asks. Setting everything to 3857 does not fix the issue of a mistaken CRS.